# How do I implement a feature where if the "Open Camera" button is clicked it opens the camera and allows to take pictures

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Basically, I have a web app that I am running using node.js backend and react on the frontend, I have a specific button I want to have an onClick feature which opens up the camera. Any idea how I have to go about this? I am a beginner at react so someone help out. Thank you in advance.
Let's assume this is the button

```
<div className= {styles.cameraCont} onClick={openCamera}>
   <p>Open Camera</p>
</div>
```

I have no clue what to make the function "openCamera" do to open the camera, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Please take a look at the [Media Capture and Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API) which allows you to access the camera. Do some research, and then ask a more specific question about what problem you have using that API.

Comment: You need to specify which camera do you want to gain access to (is it a webcam or is it a mobile device camera). If it's for the mobile device hardware than you need to use React Native Camera Module (RNCamera).

Comment: this [link](https://itnext.io/accessing-the-webcam-with-javascript-and-react-33cbe92f49cb) explains `Accessing the Webcam with JavaScript and React` hope it helps :)